# Spark JSON text field to RDD with null values

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I've got a cassandra table with a field  named table

> [app, ts, data]

I have several JSON objects inside data field in the cassandra table and I need to compute each object independently

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("datamonth")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val rdd = sc.cassandraTable[(String, String, String)]("datam", "data_month")
val jsons = rdd.map(_._3)
val jsonSchemaRDD = sqlContext.jsonRDD(jsons)
jsonSchemaRDD.registerTempTable("testjson")
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM testjson where .... ").collect
```

because of NULL values i got this error

> 17/03/02 12:00:49 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 24) java.lang.NullPointerException: Unexpected null value of column data in datam.data_month.If you want to receive null values from Cassandra, please wrap the column type into Option or use JavaBeanColumnMapper

How do i proceed ? I am new on Spark and Cassandra and don't know how can i wrap the column type into Option.

Comment: can you give some code ? I suggest you use a case class with Option for data_month. possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42122313/scala-spark-filter-rdd-using-cassandra

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30033875/spark-json-text-field-to-rdd/42552394#42552394
I tried to use this question but have problem with null values. Can i proceed without use a case class

Comment: it will be easier to help if you can provide some code

Comment: question edited